# Java Loop breaks variable not stored as expected

Tags: java, for-loop

```
public class TestIndexPeriod {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int count = 0;

                for (count = 20; count==10; count--) {
                    if (count==14)
                        break;
                }
        System.out.println(count);
    }
}
```

Why is the output 20 and not 14? If you do this the other way around and count up I was able to get hte look to break and print count as 14.

Comment: Your for loop does not even start. `count==10` is `false` at the beginning, so it goes straight to the `println`. Use `count >= 10` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Your for loop does not even start, because count is initialized as 20 and never gets to 10